# Prove that if its reduced row echelon form is $[R\; c]$ then $R$ is the reduced row echelon form of $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $[A\;b]$ be the augmented matrix of a system linear equations. Prove that if its reduced row echelon form is $[R\;c]$, then $R$ is the reduced row echelon form of $A$.

How do I prove it? I mean the question already stated it is the RREF of $[A\; b]$.

Just write about, if $R$ follows the 5 conditions, then it is RREF of $A$ or?

Comment: You are given that $[R c]$ is the RREF of $[A b]$, so therefore the augmented matrix $[R c]$ satisfies the defining properties of a RREF matrix.  You must show that the matrix $R$ also satisfies the defining properties to be a RREF matrix.

Comment: That I can do by the 5 conditions?

Comment: Assuming your definition of row reduced echelon form is given by the five conditions you refer to, then yes.